# iOS Build on Travis CI Failing due to CoreBluetooth delegate method

Tags: objective-c, travis-ci, core-bluetooth, xcodebuild, xctool

I've just set up my public repository to build on Travis. It's an iOS library, that also makes use of CoreBlueooth's delegate methods. One of which looks like this:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

When it is included in the code to be built, it causes Travis to fail the build due to it expecting a '>' after `NSDictionary<NSString *` (assumingly because it doesn't like the pointer `*` sign inside an NSDictionary key definition). However, this is the delegate method for `CBCentralManager`, so is obviously syntacticly correct.

This compiles fine on my machine, and when the particular method implementation is commented out, everything runs fine (including other CoreBluetooth delegate methods). This looks like some kind of syntax issue, but compiles fine on my end?

Comment: Could your Travis instance be running a different version of Xcode's tools?  We had that problem for a little while where our developers were using Xcode 7.x and our build machine was stuck at 6.3; a lot of the new Xcode 7 auto-completion code just plain broke Xcode 6.3 (like '_Nonnull').

Comment: @fullofsquirrels ah... apparently the default is Xcode 6.1. I shall try specifying a version now and let you know! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Travis CI defaults OS X builds to use an old Xcode version (Xcode 6.1) - as suggested by @fullofsquirrels.

This causes issues with newer syntax, and in this case caused the build to fail. Updating the `.travis.yml` file to specify the version to use fixed the issue, as follows:

```
osx_image: xcode7.2
```

Hope this helps someone!